# how to use git log to return pull-request number between tags

Tags: git, github

I tried to use git log ocmmand to retrieve all pull-request between two tags. However for some reason, one of hash does not contains PR issume number? What command I should use instead? I have tried. but same result return

```
/User$git log tag1..tag2 --pretty=oneline --date=short -- .
/User$git log tag1..tag2 --pretty=format:%h%an%s %cd --date=short -- .
```

```
hash1 (tag: tagabc) PR header (#17854)
hash2 (tag: tagabc2) PR header2
hash3 (tag: tagabc3) PR header3(#17932)
```

Comment: git is not aware of the concept of "Pull Requests". That's a GitHub concept, not a git concept. What are these tags? Who created them? Maybe some of the tags contain the PR number in their annotation and some don't? If that's the case, there's nothing much you can do other than edit the faulty tags to contain that information

Comment: `git is not aware of the concept of "Pull Requests"` - well, not exactly  https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/git-man/git-request-pull.1.en.html

Comment: @Omer no all of tag does not contains anything about pr number neither from their title. body. or description. it is from `git log` return

Comment: @jacobcan118, you may want to use a custom git command-line tool such as https://github.com/github/hub#readme

Comment: how can I use hub command to find out all git log between two tags? idea?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk. `git` is not aware of concept of PRs. Look at the branch when you pull the request. No traces can be left, or some. It completely depends on many factors.

Comment: @0andriy so how `git log` command return the issue number? i am see that from my local with `git log --pretty`

Comment: Obviously it's a part of the (title of the) commit message, relying on which is error prone.

Comment: so once pr got merged, github change the title to append pr number. so any possible reason it failed to show up when i run `git log` command

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: `git request-pull` is a command that generates an email message; it has nothing to do with GitHub pull-requests.

Comment: @0andriy @torek: thanks, I know that.  What @Omer said however is not true: `git is not aware of the concept of "Pull Requests"`. Of course it is and git `request-pull` is used in some workflows, for example in Linux kernel https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/57ce0ee0-839c-a889-0bc0-ec46985e76d3@linux.com. The mechanism of this pull requests is just different.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, no, you are mistaken. These two PRs (GitHub vs. Linux kernel flow) are from different layers, despite the same abbreviation / naming in use. What OP is talking about and what GitHub is implementing is a concept of PRs that *are being tracked* (abstract layer on top of Git). Linux kernel community uses PR to simplify merge flow (no layer on top of Git at all).

Comment: @0andriy: what are *different layers*? I use GH, are how are GH PRs *tracked*? Do you mean the web interface, API that GH provides that can be used with `hub`, review system? The goal of the pull request is the same in both GH and `git request-pull`: take changes from my branch or tree and put them in your branch or tree.